# ASP.NET MVC 4 submit 2 forms per order with one button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function in jQuery which submits to 2 forms in ASP.NET MVC 4.

What can I implement so that the first form called "fdata" is executed and once I finish checking that the submit has been successful and continue with the second form called "fbulk"?

```
$("#fdata, #fbulk").on("submit", function (e) {
        // prevent the default form-post
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post($("#fdata").prop('action'), $("#fdata").serialize(), function () {
            // first form post complete 
        });

        $.post($("#fbulk").prop('action'), $("#fbulk").serialize(), function () {
            // second form post complete 
        });
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Move the 2. post into first ones callback

Comment: If i move the 2 post it take the submit? Because the button execute the 2 forms at the same time

Comment: @BlackSD yes just move

Comment: It works like a charm, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

As @Eldar and @Sadeq Hatami said just move the second post to first post

```
$("#fdata, #fbulk").on("submit", function (e) {
        // prevent the default form-post
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post($("#fdata").prop('action'), $("#fdata").serialize(), function () {
                    $.post($("#fbulk").prop('action'), $("#fbulk").serialize(), function () {
        });
        });
    });
```